# bad balanced CURRENCY_BLOCK_GRANTED_FULL_REWARD_ZONE constant

Tags: error-log, key-image, boolberry

I have seen several Boolberry users [report a wallet and daemon error](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=577267.msg6870092#msg6870092) similar to this one:

Wallet:

> Error: transaction  was rejected by daemon with status "Failed"

Daemon:

> Transaction with id= used already spent key images [RPC1] Transaction verification failed:

I cannot find any [GitHub](https://github.com/cryptozoidberg/Boolberry) pull requests that specifically fixed this. CryptoZoidberg said "I guess it happend because wallet was  hard-closed without typing exit command."

> This issue in all cryptonote family is a result of bad balanced CURRENCY_BLOCK_GRANTED_FULL_REWARD_ZONE constant.

What does a "bad balanced CURRENCY_BLOCK_GRANTED_FULL_REWARD_ZONE constant mean? Does Monero (as part of the CryptoNote family) share this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue sounds like a wallet has a wrong view of what outputs are spent. A fix would be to rescan the wallet (`rescan_spent` or `rescan_bc` in Monero's wallet, or delete the cache file).

The "full reward zone" is completely and entirely unrelated to potential wallet sync issues.